# Comparing values but taking into account negative values

Tags: php, algorithm, numbers

I have a `$total` and a `$balance`. The balance can never be greater than the total, but BOTH could be negative. Essentially, I'm trying to see if the balance is between zero and the total.

So,

`if (($total < 0 && $balance < $total) || ($total > 0 && $balance > $total)) {
    /** BAD **/
}`

`if (between($total < 0 ? $total : 0, $total < 0 ? 0 : $total, $balance) {
    /** BAD **/
}`

are certainly 2 ways to achieve this, but is there a way to reduce the amount of logic here? Something "clever" with number theory that I am sure I should know ... but don't.

I'm using PHP, but the principle of comparison should translate from any language/algorithm.

**Feedback from comments**

If total is negative, balance must be negative and not less than total.
If total is positive, balance must be positive and not greater than total

Maybe a picture will help!

`Balance : BAD | Allowable -ve balances     | Allowable +ve balances | BAD
Total   :    -5 .. -4 .. -3 .. -2 .. -1 .. 0 .. 1 .. 2 .. 3 .. 4 .. 5`

**Further feedback**

In the question "The balance can never be greater than the total, but BOTH could be negative" ... I am talking about the magnitude, not the value. I don't think I made that clear : https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-magnitude-definition-lesson-quiz.html

**Solution**

Based upon the supplied comments.

```
<?php

class RangeTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    /**
     * @param int $balance
     * @param int $total
     * @param bool $expected
     *
     * @dataProvider provideRangeValues
     */
    public function testRange(int $balance, int $total, bool $expected)
    {
        $this->assertEquals((($total / abs($total)) * ($total - $balance) >= 0), $expected);
    }

    public function provideRangeValues()
    {
        return
            [
                'Positive Balance = Positive Total' => [10, 10, true],
                'Positive Balance < Positive Total' => [5, 10, true],
                'Positive Balance > Positive Total' => [10, 5, false],
                'Negative Balance = Negative Total' => [-10, -10, true],
                'Negative Balance < Negative Total' => [-5, -10, true],
                'Negative Balance > Negative Total' => [-10, -5, false],
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your note. Now I see, that I've misunderstood your question - I thought it was more about finance or accounting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
if (  min(1, max(-1, $total)) * ($total - $balance) >= 0 ) {

   // all good
```

Based on [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498643/comparing-values-but-taking-into-account-negative-values/52498695?noredirect=1#comment91977197_52498695), since total can never be zero. We can also do the following:

```
if ( ($total/abs($total)) * ($total - $balance) >= 0 ) {

   // all good
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yeah true! question statement made me think convoluted solution :-}

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I am actually confused now after reading question statement again. Your answer is right though

Comment: I've added some feedback to the question.

Comment: @RichardAQuadling check my edited answer now. It should work for your case. It can further be optimized if it can be guaranteed that $total can never be zero.

Comment: Total will never be zero. For entities that are zero, there will be and can be no balance in my use case.

Comment: @RichardAQuadling check my revised answer please. Two ways - both should work for you. If you are satisfied, you may kindly mark it as accepted answer (green tick) and optionally upvote . thanks :)

Comment: Almost right. Check the solution I have posted (based upon your code). Balance can equal total, so the difference calculation can be zero, so `>= 0` rather than `> 0`. Thank you!